# JavaFX - How to change color of ListView cell / OR / How loose focus on ListView, when clicking on outside of it or on a non-focusable Control?

Tags: javafx

JavaFX specific CSS or control loose focus question.

I have a **ListView**, a **TextArea** and many other controls, like Buttons and Labels on a scene. The look of them is customized via CSS and the problem is, that when I select something on the **ListView** and click outside of it, the selection (color) stays as selected (unwanted effect), unless I click on the **TextArea**, in that case it looses focus I guess and sets the color of the selected item to unselected color (wanted effect). What I want to have is for it too show the **ListView** selection as if it had no selection, when I click outside of it, regardless if the target of the click is empty space on scene or any other control (that has or does not have text focus property?).

Either a solution via CSS customization of colors or code to handle ListView would be helpful.

To understand better, see picture:
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlEsX.png)

- clicking on (2) after (1), the selection still shows with white (this is the problem)
- clicking on (3) after (1), the selection does not show (this is the desired behavior)
- difference is that (2) is a Label, and (3) is a TextArea.
- I would like the white text become green once clicking outside of ListView on any other control or empty space on the scene

CSS code:

```
.listViewPerks {
    -fx-control-inner-background: black;
    -fx-background-color: #000000;
    -fx-selection-bar: transparent;
    -fx-font-family: "Fallout Classic Dialog";
    -fx-alignment: center-left;
    -fx-font-size: 10;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-font-smoothing-type: grey;
}

.listViewPerks .list-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.listViewPerks .list-cell:filled {
    -fx-text-fill: #38FB00;
}

.listViewPerks:focused .list-cell:filled:selected:focused {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.list-cell:filled:selected:focused,
.list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Just in case it helps, problematic ListView (with full source of project) can be found here: https://github.com/Sasabmeg/foclassic-char-planner/blob/main/src/main/java/net/fodev/foclassic/controller/LevelUpController.java

I have tried to code some dirty solution with listener on focus change, but not working, as clicking on Label would not trigger it.

````
App.getScene().focusOwnerProperty().addListener((prop, oldNode, newNode) -> {
    System.out.println("App.getScene().focusOwnerProperty() -> " + prop + " / " + oldNode + " / " + newNode);
});```
````

Comment: The colors indicate the state of the control (list cell, in this case): is it selected? Is it focused? If you were to change the color to indicate it's not focused when it actually is, then the application would be in an inconsistent state, resulting in poor (or possibly unusable, for some users) user experience. If you want to actually move the focus elsewhere, just make the controls that don't receive focus by default focus traversable. (Though you should probably have some visual indication as to where the focus currently is.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the key word 'focus traversable' that you mentioned helped me search for more appropriate results. For now I have disabled focus on the ListView, since I found no better solution for what I wanted and due to effort/gain on this subject.